# passing variable from page to page react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a uid from firebase, but it is stored like this:

checkout.js

```
 firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
  if(user) {
    console.log(user.uid)
   }
 });
```

the `user.uid` stores the uid I need to pass to another page. this uid is stored in `checkout.js`, and I need to get it to `profile.js` to use the uid there. how would I do this?
please let me know if more code is needed. I am using react / js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I literally just copy and pasted that code into the `profile.js` and it worked.

Comment: That may have worked but is far from the correct ( and better ) way to achieve this. This is done either using a state-management framework like Redux or the built-in Context or using cookies.

Answer (score 1):

use a context store

create the store and the hook

```
const FirebaseAuthContext = createContext()

export function useAuth() {
    const context = useContext(FirebaseAuthContext)
    if (!context && typeof window !== 'undefined') {
        throw new Error(`useAuth must be used within a FirebaseAuthContext`)
    }
    return context
}
```

Create the Provider

```
export function FirebaseAuthProvider(props) {
    const [authState, setAuthState] = useState({
        isLoggedIn: false,
        currentUser: null,
        pending: true,
    })

    useEffect(() => {
        const unregisterAuthObserver = auth().onAuthStateChanged(async (currentUser) => {
            
            if (currentUser) {
             
                 setAuthState({. isLoggedIn: true, pending: false, currentUser})

            } else {
                setAuthState({ ...authState, currentUser: null, pending: false })
            }
        })

        return () => unregisterAuthObserver()
    }, [])

 return <FirebaseAuthContext.Provider value={authState}>{props.children}</FirebaseAuthContext.Provider>
```

Wrap your app with provider

```
<FirebaseAuthProvider><App /></FirebaseAuthProvider>
```

Then wherever you need to validate the user.

```
const { currentUser, pending } = useAuth();

if (currentUser && pending) //pending authentication

if (currentUser) // user is login, uid is in currentUser.uid
```